# How to post on blogger using api v3

Tags: php, curl, blogger

Here is my code. Its not working for me. its output is Not found. Can anyone please tell me. What it is trying to find. I am using curl.

```
 $datas =array(
'kind' => 'blogger#post',
'blog' => array('id' => '3830391901953093498'),
'title' => 'This is title',
'content' => 'With <b>exciting</b> content...'
 );
 $data_json = json_encode($datas, JSON_HEX_QUOT + JSON_HEX_TAG + JSON_HEX_AMP +    JSON_HEX_APOS + JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
 $dat = strlen($data_json);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3830391901953093498/posts&access_token='.$sd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $dat);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
$rep=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is $sd is access token that is

```
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
$kd = json_decode($token);
 $sd = $kd->access_token;
```

Please tell me where Am I wrong.

Comment: Uhhh that's because you have extra space in the URL address? It went `posts&access_to     ken`.

Comment: Sorry I didnot post it correctly

Comment: Did you check that the URL is properly formed? Printing it or dumping it on the screen will help to see if anything is missing. Also, you are using some PHP constants: are you sure they're defined?

Comment: Yes, sir it is defined and I have used oauthplayground. and it use same url. I can insert post from oauthplayground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use it. Hope it works for you.

```
$blogger = new Google_Service_Blogger($client);
try {
$blog = $blogger->blogs->getByUrl("http://hollywood159.blogspot.in");
   // creates a post
   $mypost = new Google_Service_Blogger_Post();
   $mypost->setTitle("the title");
   $mypost->setLabels("my labels array");
   $mypost->setContent("my content");
   $blogger->posts->insert($blog->getId(), $mypost);

   }
```

Comment: How can I upload video file to my blog post. I don't want to use youtube for that and upload video directly in my post

Comment: @Shawon - I highly appreciate your great help. Thanks a lot dear!

Answer (score 0):

according to this page: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost you are going to need the auth token in the header

```
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
```